# Group several custom global page templates in sub-folder

Tags: theme-development, page-template

I have to create several [global page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use), and, in order to keep them organized, would like to have them in a subfolder. So far I don't know how to do it, the t[emplate-parts/page/...](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/#page-templates-folder) structure is not meant for this purpose.

Any idea or alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group them under custom folder "templates" or any other name and it will work